# bash: only process line if not in second file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have this block of code:

```
 while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [ "$line" != "" ]; then
        echo -e "$lanIP\t$line" >> /tmp/ipList;
    fi
done < "/tmp/includeList"
```

I know this must be really simple.  But I have another list (/tmp/excludeList).  I only want to echo the line within my while loop if the line ins't found in my excludeList.  How do I do that.  Is there some awk statement or something?

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use grep

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ -n ${line} ]] \
        && ! grep -xF "$line" excludefile &>/dev/null; then
       echo -e "$lanIP\t$line" >> /tmp/ipList;
    fi
done < "/tmp/includeList"
```

the -n $line means if $line is not empty 
the grep returns true if $line is found in exclude file which is inverted by the ! so returns true if the line is not found.
  -x means line matched so nothing else can appear on the line
  -F means fixed string so if any metacharacters end up in $line they'll be matched literally.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this is really close.  It doesn't seem to work because my includeList doesn't have a line break at the end of the last line and my excludeList does.  So, essentially, I need it to not worry about whether or not there is a line break at the end of the lines.

Comment: try ditching the -x on the grep.

Comment: Try running the time command on the above vs the awk or grep-only solutions posted and I expect you'll find this is at least one order of magnitude slower. It's the wrong approach.

Comment: In this case my lists are very small and this solution performs well enough.

Comment: Probably all of the answers would work.  Some might be faster than others.  This answer worked for me and I selected it because it required the least amount of change to my existing code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `grep` alone:

```
$ cat file
blue
green
red
yellow
pink

$ cat exclude 
green
pink

$ grep -vx -f exclude file
blue
red
yellow
```

The `-v` flag tells `grep` to only output the lines in `file` that are not found in `exclude` and the `-x` flags forces whole line matching.

Comment: problem with that though is that if any line in exclude does not match line grep will return true, so not really useful to decide if a line is not in the file.

Comment: Why does the exit status matter, you only want to process lines in `file` that are not in `exclude` so just `grep -vx -f exclude file | process..`?

Comment: Ah yeah if you filter with grep prior to the redirection to the while loop. I was thinking about greping the exclude file from inside the loop.

Comment: @peteches I don't think looping is required here at all, majority of occasion if you are greping inside a loop you probably could be doing it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk -v ip=$lanIP -v OFS="\t" '
    NR==FNR {exclude[$0]=1; next}
    /[^[:space:]]/ && !($0 in exclude) {print ip, $0}
' /tmp/excludeList /tmp/includeList > /tmpipList
```

This reads the exclude list info an array (as the array keys) -- the `NR==FNR` condition is true while awk is reading the first file from the arguments. Then, while reading the include file, if the current line contains a non-space character and it does not exist in the exclude array, print it.

The equivalent with grep:

```
grep -vxF -f /tmp/excludeList /tmp/includeList | while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ -n "$line" ]] && printf "%s\t%s\n" "$ipList" "$line"
done > /tmp/ipList
```